# jQuery add class based on CSS characteristics

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, jquery-events

I am looking for a method with jQuery (or plain JS) in which to build a conditional on whether a div has a specific CSS characteristic.

For example, I want jQuery to add `position:fixed` to an element's CSS when another element is set to `display:none`, though change back to `position:relative` on the first element when the second element changes to `display:block`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your change is event driven you just add the code to your event handlers
so if element one is made hidden by a click - make element 2 position fixed

```
    $("#element_one").click(function(){
 $("#element_one").hide();
    $("#element_two").css({"position":"fixed"});
    })
```

if you just want to watch elements you will need timers (although I cannot really imagine a scenario where you do not trigger the change by either an event of programaticaly)

```
watchInterval = setInterval("watchMe()",10)

function watchMe(){
if ($("element_one").is(":hidden") ) {
 $("#element_two").css({"position":"fixed"});
}
}
```

Comment: I didn't think this would work, but I changed some of the script up and the first solution you provided ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#elOne').css('display') == 'none' ? $('#elAnother').css({'position':'fixed'}) : $('#elAnother').css({'position':'relative'});
```

Would that do the trick?

or perhaps :

```
$('#elOne').is(':hidden') ? $('#elAnother').css({'position':'fixed'}) : $('#elAnother').css({'position':'relative'});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not any nice way of doing this as you cannot "spy" on CSS changes, though jQuery does have a [watch plugn](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/watch) which can monitor changes on certain properties. Your best bet is to use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.getComputedStyle) which will get the real CSS values used for any object and act accordingly.